# How to use the UWP LockScreen API for a lock screen replacement app?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Microsoft has [what appears to be an interesting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.lockscreen) for creating a lock screen replacement. Unfortunately, there is close to no documentation on how to use it, or rather I am too thick to understand the existing documentation (not having much prior UWP development experience).

So far, the closest thing I've found to an answer on how to use this API is [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb06561e-4a98-4716-80c0-0efe00c14161/uwplockscreen-question?forum=wpdevelop), which upon further inspection is simply copy-pasted from the documentation for [`LockScreenUnlockingDeferral`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.lockscreen.lockscreenunlockingdeferral):

> To show an unlock animation, your lock screen app must:
>
> - Register to be notified of unlocking via the Unlocking event.
> - In the Unlocking event handler, call GetDeferral.
> - Kick off an animation.+ When that animation completes, call Complete on the deferral to end the deferral.

I guess my first question would be how to simply "register to be notified of unlocking". Apologies if this is a very simple question, but I am in the position of knowing so little that I don't even know what I should be searching for answers. I've attempted to find some sample code online, but as far as I can tell nobody else has publicized an attempt to create a lock screen replacement app, and [Microsoft's own UWP sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples) contains no information on how to use this API. The closest thing I can find there is information on [exposing app info to the lock screen](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/LockScreenApps), which is not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That this is documented at all is because anybody can see these classes in the WinRT metadata files.  But there is no public sample available for it and the docs are insufficient to learn how to use it.  Given how security-critical a lock screen replacement is, you'd have to assume this is privileged info that is available only to partner companies.

Comment: That's very disappointing. I was looking into user authentication APIs and other (seemingly obvious?) related functions this would have to deal with, and I was not able to find any documentation on the actual authentication part of the unlock process. This leads me to suspect that the "lock screen app" is simply supposed to replace the splash screen thing that currently appears before the password screen, but again, no documentation.

Comment: @Ernest3.14 This namespace is protected by a Windows capability, so it is not available to third parties. You could see here:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/726

Comment: Given that the source is Raymond Chen, I guess I can trust it... It's unfortunate that this has not been "clarified in the documentation" yet. Thank you for the link.